# Avant Garde Enthusiasts (drone, noise etc..)    

Tags: sound-design, community, ambience, drone

I hope everyone enjoyed their Christmas. I've been meaning to put this up for a while, but i've been hesitant because I don't wanna look like some weirdo. Like the title suggests i'm pretty much into making this kind of sound, but I've noticed that not many people are into it where i'm from (Dublin). I was hoping to meet people on the forum who had like minded interests, and was maybe into making similar kind of stuff. It would be cool to talk, share ideas, music, recommendations etc... It would be great to setup a little community, a blog, or chat over the net, that would be sweet. If anyone is interested, or just wants to ridicule the idea , just send me a p.m. It would be great to meet individuals who are doing this, as i'm pretty much alone and it sucks. 
Thanks.

( I know this is the whole point in a forum, but I just wanted to get to know people who are doing this, as it's pretty annoying when your friends tell you that just sounds like noise  )

Hope everyone had a good Christmas.

Comment: Haha! You have to go to Harvestworks if you ever come to new york, they're all about that stuff, check out their vimeo profile vimeo.com/harvestworksnyc
I've found myself recording a few ensembles in that field, recently

Comment: @Verkannt, welcome to SSD!

Comment: yes, yes it would. I've just drank three bottles of wine so now might not be the best time to talk about it but feel free to email me.

Comment: I live in West Virginia... I have a horrible time finding people to chat with about the subject haha.
Even when I went to music school for piano and composition, I was the only person who ever seemed to be into Milton Babbitt, Ryoji Ikeda, Xenakis, etc.
Though I've had to write a lot more accessible music, I have a modest repertoire of experimental stuff. I'd love to discuss and shares ideas/artists:)

Comment: @hundred hundred, thanks for the reply. If you want I can send you my e-mail address? I don't think it is possible to pm, is it?

@Jay Jennings Thank you Jay.

@James Hubble That would be great James. Can you send me your e-mail?

Comment: @Filipe, I will check that out Filipe. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not sure how to send messages on this site to give e-mail etc. hahaha 

Comment: Welcome and thanks for posting, Verkannt. One of my side projects is a long-distance avant-garde/experimental duo called Donny Who Loved Bowling. We've got a couple of albums out on iTunes/CD Baby etc. though you can get a taste at http://donnywholovedbowling.wordpress.com/

I'd love to hear what you're up to, and yes, setting up some sort of online community (if one doesn't exist already and we don't know about it) would be cool.

Answer (score 2):

hello!  I am also a fan of experimental music of all sorts.  My productions tend to be more beat oriented but I love doing DJ mixes of ambient/dron/noise stuff.  A few years ago I did a noise retrospective mix with music from 1913 to 2007, tracing the genealogy of noise music, which for me is simply the exploration of SOUND.  Perhaps you would enjoy it:

http://www.spannered.org/radio/1152/

I also have some more experimental music mixes here that you might enjoy:
http://www.mixcloud.com/PrinceMarolo/

Feel free to message, I love exchanging ideas about music

Answer (score 1):

Its a pretty broad definition but I listen to (& sometimes make) some of these kinds of music (although I tend towards the more minimal in approach) but there are lots of existing communities online for this subject, a few worth checking out:

http://www.12k.com/forum
http://www.muffwiggler.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=22
http://www.noiseguide.com/board/
http://ihatemusic.noquam.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is my band, "Prótesis para una Bailarina"

[vimeo]18450231[/vimeo]

Answer (score 0):

I was lucky to have been exposed to experimental/musique concrete/electro-acoustic genres from a fairly early age. One of the most amazing places that remained undiscovered until the iron curtain came down was the old Czechoslokaia. There, people like Iva Bitova, Achu-Achu, The Plastic People of the Universe, Pulnoc all were sercretly performing behind the governments backs with there own fusion of jazz/ambiant/opera/classical/rock combination's. A wonderful time for the west when they were finally exposed to the rest of the world. There are clips on YouTube of many from that part of the world.

In  Montreal, there has been an experimental movement that has spanned decades with the likes of David Christian, Ned Bouhalassa and Jean-Claude Pellerin. The influence of Pierre Schaffier is huge there. Check it out on the net.

I am not sure if NY's Knitting Factory is still going but I have a number of compilations on CD from the 90's.

There are many of us out there.

Answer (score 0):

@Verkannt Great Idea! Im from Venezuela. maybe we can make a group on facebook or something. add me artix69@hotmail.com Greetings!!!

Some of my sounds!( there are few of them )
http://www.freesound.org/usersViewSingle.php?id=1760507

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about the Avant Garde Project?

http://www.avantgardeproject.org/

Actually it has now shut down which is very sad.. Didn't find out until now.  This guy was hosting dozens and dozens and dozens of hard to find avant garde electronic music recordings - most of which were unavailable on modern formats.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a terrific site with lots of experimental recordings and films, both from renowned and also less known artists. It's called Ubu Web (hope some of you are familiar with 'Pataphysics)

[ubuweb.com](http://www.ubuweb.com/)

For example, there's a hard to find documentary about John Cage called "I Have Nothing to Say and I Am Saying It" (1990). Highly recommended.

[ubu.com/film/cage_masters.html](http://www.ubu.com/film/cage_masters.html)

Comment: Great, thanks for that, found a SunRa documentary!

Answer (score 0):

Hi!
You might also check some of these noise labels and sites. That might be good starting point for your own researches on that kind of music. Just to get you some input and inspiration.

NoFunFest New York - annual Noise Festival held in Brookly, New York; check out their previous lineups too!
 - http://www.nofunfest.com/

**Two discussions on that topic on DIS**
 - http://drownedinsound.com/community/boards/music/4215886 and  http://drownedinsound.com/community/boards/music/4266241

**Labels / Mailorder and the like:**

Southern Records - http://www.southern.net/

Haesten & Korset - http://hastenochkorset.blogspot.com/

Econore - http://www.econore.com

Hospital Productions - http://hospitalproductions.net/

A-Musik - http://www.a-musik.com/

NotNotFun - http://www.notnotfun.com/

Licht-ung - http://www.licht-ung.de/

Toxic Factory Records -http://toxicfactoryrecords.blogspot.com/

Slowboy - http://www.slowboy.de/

there are a lot more! Those were just the ones that popped in my mind now...

Hope that helps and you didn't already knew this. And ifyou have any sounds to listen to, tell us where we can hear it!